# $PATH variable for anonymous user

Tags: php, centos, path

I'm on CentOS.

I have a php script that needs to have /usr/lib64 in its $PATH.

From the php script when I output

> echo $PATH

I get

> /bin:/usr/bin

when I ouput

> echo $USER

I get a 1 character long blank space.

I created a custom.sh in /etc/profile.d  with

> PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64
>
> export PATH

I logged in logged out using SSH several times. I also tried

> source /etc/profile

to no avail, as my script still only has /bin and /usr/bin in its $PATH

Any ideas, pointers ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

PHP is run via HTTPd. Modify the `httpd` initscript to frob `$PATH` appropriately.